# Load Tensorflow Lite models in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tinyml

I'm working on a TinyML project using Tensorflow Lite with both quantized and float models. In my pipeline, I train my model with the `tf.keras` API and then convert the model to a TFLite model. Finally, I quantize the TFLite model to int8.
I can save and load the "normal" tensorflow model with the API `model.save` and `tf.keras.model.load_model`

Is it possible to do the same with the converted TFLite models? Going through the quantization process every time is quite time-consuming.

Comment: You mean you want to get inference directly from tflite model just after convert it, without deploying it on the other device?

Comment: Yes, I need a way to save the TFLite models on disk so that I can load them the next day and do inference in my python notebook. Currently, I can only save and load the tensorflow model, but I always have to go through the quantization before I can do inference with TFLite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [tflite interpreter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter) to get inference from TFLite models directly in notebook.

Here is an example of a model for image classification. Let's say we have a tflite model as:

```
tflite_model_file = 'converted_model.tflite'
```

Then we can load  and test it like this:

```
# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
with open(tflite_model_file, 'rb') as fid:
    tflite_model = fid.read()
    
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]

# Gather results for the randomly sampled test images
predictions = []

test_labels, test_imgs = [], []
for img, label in tqdm(test_batches.take(10)):
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, img)
    interpreter.invoke()
    predictions.append(interpreter.get_tensor(output_index))
    
    test_labels.append(label.numpy()[0])
    test_imgs.append(img)
```

Note that you can just inference from the tflite models. You are not able to make changes in architecture and layers, like reloading Keras models. If you want to change the architecture, you should save the Keras model, and test it until you get satisfactory results, then convert it to tflite.

Comment: I did not realize that I could just load the tflite model as a binary. Sometimes the simple solutions are so straightforward that it's hard to spot them. Thanks!